# How to win the next promotion - company in flux, short on experience, high on ability?

Tags: career-development, communication, careers

This is an example but say I work in a big company. Say we got a new CEO with proven leadership abilities who is introducing big changes. As those changes are coming along and the company is getting bigger he is turning to all of his previous co-workers, connections,  employees he's worked with before to come fill in all the new(and/or important) positions that have opened up. Of course he knows their abilities so I completely understand the reasoning. However, I have valuable skill set and abilities and I'm only shorter in experience compared to those people. But I do have great potential. So how do I turn his attention to me and show him that even though he hasn't seen me in action, I can contribute a lot? If I wasn't recognized by the old management, how can I make the new management give me an opportunity to grow before they've filled all the spots with employees from previous business ventures?

Lets also say there are a bunch of on going projects that I can participate in. I want to take the leadership so I can shine but how can I possibly do it in an elegant way?

Comment: Contribute a lot and talk with your manager regarding your contributions.

Comment: Everyone has great potential, no?  The key to my mind is how well can you show results with those skills and abilities you have to make the business successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple and obvious answer is to outperform your co-workers and volunteer to take on more challenging tasks with more responsibility. The new CEO is bringing in talent from his/her past because they are known entities and proven performers (or just friends, but we can't assume that).

Tell your manager that you want to take on more responsibility. Think of a new project idea that would save the company money or create revenues, write up a proposal, and volunteer to lead the new effort. You need to think of creative solutions to problems that perhaps the company is not yet addressing or even aware of. Think about new initiatives, design how they can be implemented, and show how you can lead.

If you have a great presentation that shows a new way to save or make money, you will get noticed. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @fecak. I do have a couple of ideas what can be done so I'll go for it

Answer (score 3):

True leaders are noticed when they stand up and take control of a chaotic or neglected situation, not when they ask for more responsibilities.  The answer is simple really, like others have stated, you become noticed by outperforming others, but you must also have strong interpersonal skills and an unapologetic approach to naturally stepping up to lead an effort when nobody else will.

Leaders take ownership and care about the work that needs to be accomplished. This isn't something that just gets delegated if it is to be done right.  Then when this is noticed trust is hopefully built and before you know it, you are in the inner circle of the New Order.

Does this mean that you are right to trust the new guard and his posse?  This is a different matter altogether and depends on the underlying motivations of the new CEO.  If the board expects him to clean house he will probably start evaluating where there is fat to be trimmed and get rid of all but critically important people that were there before.  Other opaque motivations might be like one place I worked where the new CIO came in to a health system bringing his people with the intention of giving them insider information to the industry that they needed to be successful at a new startup he was planning.  His plan was to fire so many IT people to the point where the organization suffered, then resign and start his IT services company that would overcharge that very organization to help save them from the mess that he created.

In this situation you will likely NEVER get the trust or leadership that you want because of ulterior motives.